# The Time Freezing Room - Theoretically possible?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, spacetime, time-dilation, time-travel

Imagine a room in your basement with a very special property: The time inside this room runs 60 times faster compared to the outside world. That means when you enter the room and spend there 1 day with working, reading, etc., only 24 minutes are gone in the outside world. Wouldn't such a place be wonderful:

- You would be done with all your university exercises in just a few hours.
- You could read so many books and become one of the most educated people.
- You could practice many skills... you could become a great musician and learn any instruments in just a week (1 week = 14 month), or become expert in any other skill...
- You could run your simulations on a computer in this room and they would be done in little time.
- You could maybe even grow some food in such a room.

The concept of such a room sparked my imagination, so my first question is:

> **For what would You use such a room? What great possibilities are there?**

However, I study physics and I am very curious for the (theoretical) ways to actually build such a room. Of course this room is more like a thought experiment, but: Is it possible to build such a place in accordance with the laws of physics? Or:

> **How to build such a room?**

Thank you for your answers.

**Note:** Before I asked this question I checked if it matches the physics category, but according to [Is non-mainstream physics appropriate for this site?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4538/is-non-mainstream-physics-appropriate-for-this-site/4539#4539) it should be fine: *"For example, a question that proposes a new concept or paradigm, but asks for evaluation of that concept within the framework of current (mainstream) physics is OK."*

Comment: People outside would see you grow old very fast if you spent too much time in that room...

Comment: Well, yes, thanks. However, you would still have advantages as running simulations, growing food, etc...

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the longest elapsed time along a world line happens on a geodesic, that is when a body is at rest. So you cannot have time "accelerate", you can only "slow it down" relatively to a reference frame by accelerating in a very strong manner (leaving a place very fast and coming back there would work, as made famous by the so-called "twins paradox").

So to make your room, you would have to send the whole outside world away for a close-to-lightspeed trip (and back) whenever you feel like "entering" it. That "room" cannot be a place...

You would have to actually leave the "room", the place where your food grows or your computer simulation run, go on a relativistic round trip yourself and then indeed upon return observe that your 10000-years simulation is over while for you a few days passed. But then the situation would have been "you in a forward time travel room".

Comment: Rollandin But if you have to send the whole outside world in a speed, then why isn't it possible the other way? I mean I am also seeing that I am speeding and the world is still.

Comment: @AsifIqubal. Because acceleration is not symmetrical: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/13767/109928