# Rotation in an 'empty' universe

Tags: rotation, centrifugal-force, machs-principle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is rotational motion relative to space?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1372/is-rotational-motion-relative-to-space)

Assume a universe with the same physics as ours, but containing only one rotating (charge-free) body - let's say the size of the Earth. Would the rotation cause a bulge at the equator of the rotating body?

Comment: +1. ..I was about to comment with side question how will gyroscopes react to the turns then got a brain freeze

Comment: Why not? In our universe, what's the answer and why?

Comment: I really feel that knowing this part will make me a better human and citizen. May be it is more relevant to some 18th century study, but it will be so nice to see the understandable answer.

Comment: Einstein may give Mach some credit for molding his thinking, but Einsteins theory's put Mach's ideas firmly in the trash bin. Einstein tells us that physics is local, so Mach can take a flying leap as his arguments revolved around a purely non-local argument.

Comment: What do you mean by rotating? ...rotating with respect to what?

Comment: Since it's rotating around itself, and since it's a massive object (so there's gravity), then I guess yes. There will be an equatorial bulge.

Comment: I'm tempted to say the answer to the question is 'no', in the sense that you can't really talk about rotation unless there is other matter present in the universe. Mach's principle, as interpreted by Einstein in GR, relies on the presence of distant matter to make sense of rotating reference frames.

Comment: @kleingordon umm, if we were part of that rotating body, can't we use a Foucault pendulum to talk about its rotation around itself? (I'm talking classical physics. I don't know how to think about this problem in terms of relativity.)

Comment: This has been asked many times before. http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1372/is-rotational-motion-relative-to-space   http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/3986/newtons-bucket   http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/13008/inertia-in-an-empty-universe  http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/13767/how-are-accelerated-reference-frames-non-symmetrical/13768#13768   http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/173/is-acceleration-an-absolute-quantity http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1048/what-if-the-universe-is-rotating-as-a-whole