# What is the present state of Mach's Principle amongst physicists?

Tags: inertia, machs-principle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is Mach’s Principle Wrong?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5483/is-machs-principle-wrong)

I'm doing research on gravitation and inertial forces and would like to know what is the place that Mach's Principle is occupying nowadays in the scientific community. Has it had any further developments in the past few years? Is is not considered Physics, or more towards Philosophy?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this has been well covered in [Is Mach's Principle Wrong?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/5483/) so I am going to close it for now.