# Which force acts as centripetal force on gyroscope?

Tags: angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics, gyroscopes, precession

I think I have understood gyroscope in terms of angular momentum and how the torque of gravitational force moves it the way it does.

Also I understand the direction in which it would move:
[What determines the direction of precession of a gyroscope?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/47461/102169)

And the working : https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/226485/102169

I saw a couple of videos about it:
 https://youtu.be/ty9QSiVC2g0

https://youtu.be/GeyDf4ooPdo

Note how the wheel rotates around. So the Centre of Mass of the wheel goes around the wheel in a horizontal circle. Which force acts on the system of Rod and the Wheel that makes it perform circular motion?

I see it analogous to a particle performing circular motion or a rod being rotated about one of its end (a compound system).

Since the string attached would only pull it up, I understand why it doesn't fall off against gravity but why does it perform circular motion without a centripetal force?

Is anything wrong in my analogy? Or is there a force I don't see?

Answer (score 1):

The point about which the gyroscope pivots provides the centripetal force: this is either friction, or some hinge mechanism.

Comment: What if I tie that to a vertical string? What applies force in horizontal direction? If you could please watch the little video I linked above. The first one that is. Can you explain what is happening there? Thanks. Appreciate your effort.

Comment: The string is not vertical and so is able to provide a component of the tension which provides the force to produce the centripetal acceleration of the centre of mass.