# Gyroscopic precession force translated 90 degrees?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, angular-momentum, gyroscopes, precession

I was watching a video on propeller gyroscopic effect, please take a look at this 1 minute segment (up to 6:06):

https://youtu.be/QGWbjGqmoWo?t=307

Alternatively, here is a summarizing image from the above video:

[image]

Could you please explain mathematically why the person says that, when a force is applied at one point on the gyroscope, its effect gets translated by 90 degrees in the direction in which the gyroscope is turning? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What determines the direction of precession of a gyroscope?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/47461/)