# How? Calculate torque from twisting a gyroscope

Tags: angular-momentum, gyroscopes

Please be patient, I'm not a physics guy.

I'm building a **robot that flips itself over using a gyroscope**.
The gyroscope spins horizontaly at first, then a servo changes the gyro's rotating axis, making the robot flip in the opposite direction.
[image: diagram]
How can I calculate the **torque of the flip**, given:

- gyro's rotational speed (rpm or equivalent)
- gyro's diameter
- gyro's mass
- speed at which rotating axis is changed

Is there a formula for this?

Comment: I think the size and mass properties of the robot play a role, as the resistance flipping depends on the location of the wheels in contact. Unless the robot is floating in space :-)

Comment: I'm just interested in the torque the gyro will output for this question. Pretend the robot has zero mass.

Comment: The formula given by Cleonis for the moment of inertia is not correct. See my answer to a related question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/528129/how-much-force-is-required-to-break-precession/800667#800667

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before giving the formula, note that the response of the gyroscope wheel will not be in *opposite* direction.

For names of direction of rotation let me use the standard names of [aircraft principle axes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_principal_axes): *roll*, *pitch* and *yaw*.

Take the spin axis of the gyro wheel as rolling, and apply a large torque that will pitch the gyro wheel fast. Then in response the gyro wheel will yaw.
But then: if that yawing motion is fast too it will itself give rise to a response.
So: to construct a robot that can flip itself is not straightforward. I'm guessing it can be done, but be prepared to see first attempts move in a way that is counter-intuitive to you.

As to a formula:

The usual letter for rotation rate is the greek letter 'omega' $\omega$
I will use a subscript to distinguish between spin rate and pitch rate

The usual letter for torque is the greek letter 'tau' $\tau$

I will use an expression for a highly simplified configuration, a wheel with *all* of its mass located at the outer rim. Of course an actual wheel is a disk. Still: usually a gyro wheel has as large proportion of its mass close to the rim. You will need to guess the error that is introduced by this simplification so you can compensate for it.

spin rate: $\omega_s$
pitch rate: $\omega_p$
wheel mass: $M$
wheel radius: $R$

formula for the magnitude of the resulting torque when a spinning gyro wheel is pitched:

$$ \tau = \omega_s \omega_p M R^2 $$

---

Responding to a comment:

There is the dimensionality check:
dimensionality of torque: $Nm$
Hence: dimensionality of torque: $M L^2 T^{-2}$
(kilogram, meter, meter, per second, per second)

There is the consistency with the following approximate formula of rate of precession (L for angular momentum of the spinning gyro wheel):

$$ \omega_p = \frac{\tau}{L} $$

(The above formula is a good approximation only when the rate of precession is slow compared to the spin rate. When the rate of precession is fast then the angular momentum of the precession is a significant contribution.)

(My apologies for not  giving the derivation I used. I concur that I really should. I integrated around the rim of the gyro wheel. That is an unusual derivation method, so if I were to give the derivation here I would have to explain many of the steps.)

Comment: How is this formula derived? The dimensionality is suspect as $\omega_s \omega_p$ isn't in units of `radians/second^2`.

Comment: @ja72 I added to the answer, showing that the dimensionality check comes out good, and I mention consistency with a standard approximate formula for rate of precession.

Comment: What are the units of each variable in your first formula?

Comment: @botspot About the units of the factors in the formula: what is on the left hand side of the formula must be expressed in the same units as what is on the right hand side. So if you would express the mass in grams then the torque must be interpreted in terms of grams. The formula is not inherently in particular units (kilogram, gram, etc); whatever unit you choose: left hand side must be consistent with right hand side.

Comment: @Cleonis, I mean if ωs = 6000, ωp = 10, M = 10, and R = 20, then τ = 240000000. OK great, now what?

Comment: @Botspot About the concept of torque: how to make use of that concept is well searcheable (wikipedia, etc.). It could be that that you expect the information that you need will be spoonfed to you. If so, that is an unreasonable expectation. To build what you want to build involves a judgement call to choose build strategy: a) complete trial and error; b) use calculation to get some ballpark figures and trial and error from there. Closest analogy to your plan is the [Cubli](https://phys.org/news/2013-12-zurich-team-cubli-video.html), which doesn't use gyro wheels, but reaction wheels.

Answer (score 0):

For a spinning flywheel, the external torque vector determines the rate of change of the angular momentum vector , L, which equals Iw.  For a uniform disk, I, (The rotational inertia) = (½) m R^2, and the angular velocity vector, w, (in radians/sec) is defined as being along the axis of rotation. (You may want to look up the associated “right hand rules”.)  The problem is, when you push on the axle of a spinning flywheel, it does not move in the direction of your push, so that the direction of applied torque and the reaction torque change with time.

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics SE.  Please, use laTex notation for formulae. It's about writing them in between of dollar symbols, and laTex commands inside, like this `$v^2=\frac{GM}{r}$` . See here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference