# Feynman Lectures: 20–3 The gyroscope

Tags: rotational-dynamics, gyroscopes, coriolis-effect, precession

In the The Feynman Lectures on Physics, Volume I, Chapter 20, Section 3,The Gyroscope found [here](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_20.html), Feynman wrote

> We note that when the wheel is precessing, the particles that are going around the wheel are not really moving in a plane because the wheel is precessing (see Fig. 20–4). As we explained previously (Fig. 19–4), the particles which are crossing through the precession axis are moving in curved paths, and this requires application of a lateral force. This is supplied by our pushing on the axle, which then communicates the force to the rim through the spokes.

Can someone please explain how the forces $F$ applied in Fig. 20-2 are lateral? I would have thought that the lateral force needed to be applied along the y-axis instead of the z-axis in order to supply the force needed to make the particle travel in the curve shown in Fig. 20-4 similar to Fig. 19-4. I can't figure out what this has to do with the Coriolis-effect which Fig. 19.4 is demonstrating.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Figure 19.4 looks down on a turntable. So the rotational axis (positive y axis) points up, out of the page. lateral forces are applied in the x-z plane. Right?

Comment: Yep, I agree with that. Do you know how the other axes relate?

Answer (score 0):

I can’t see the numbered figures, so let me walk you through a slightly different physical example: a helicopter rotor.

Imagine the rotor is turning counterclockwise views from above. A rotor blade goes from “ahead” to “left” to “behind” to “right”.

Now imagine you provide an impulse down on a blade tip at the front, up on a blade at the back. Normally, you’d expect the rotor to move down at the front, up at the back: tilt forward.

But note what’s really happening: the impulse is a force for a time, which is a *velocity* change. Only after a time will it become a position change.

So when the rotor is turning, the blade is moving right to left at the front. The impulse adds a small downward component to the large right-left speed: the blade tip starts moving on the diagonal. It *doesnt* move down right at the front. It starts moving down, but only gets down by the time the rotor blade has moved to the left: the turning rotor tilts to the left, not forward.

If you want a rotating rotor, gyroscope or other object to rotate in a particular way, you have to exert the torque 90 degrees before in the rotation.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Can you explain what you mean when you say: "the impulse is a force for a time, which is a velocity change. Only after a time will it become a position change." -Thanks!

Comment: That’s basic mechanics:  F=ma means that F delta t = m delta v

Comment: Are you suggesting that for every rotation rate, no matter how small or how large, the timing *always* comes out in such a way that the effects of the exerted force occur 90 degrees later? For instance, let the helicopter rotor rotate at an anguler velocity of one revolution per minute. With such a low angular velocity, will the response still be 90 degrees delayed? So: we have that the explanation you offered fails very visibly at low rotation rates. Unfortunately, this explanation fails for *every* rotation rate, it's just that at high rotation rate the failure is harder to spot.

Comment: @cleonis Timing is not relevant: the motion is constrained to be circular rotation, so it’s 90 degrees of shift, not some number of seconds. Clearly the behavior at low rate is different from high rate; the answer mentions that. The exact answer is $L+\tau \delta t$, but the Question seems to need a conceptual answer, not a mathematical one.

Comment: @BobJacobsen The point is, this is so elementary that failure in one case implies complete failure. The 90-degrees-delayed explanation is like proposing a *Universal law of gravity* while acknowledging that it fails for the planet Mercury. But if it fails *visibly* for Mercury it is in fact failing for *all* planets, the failure just happens to be below detection level. The fact that the 90 degrees delayed idea fails for slow rotation rates carries the implication that it fails for all rotation rates. No wiggle room: any proposed mechanism is either correct for all cases, or totally wrong.

Comment: And yet Newtonian gravity is still useful, as is this explanation. Physics is not mathematics, and rarely exact. But in case, for a spinning gyroscope, the 90 degrees is exact. Don’t believe it? Give me a non-zero L and torque that gives another result.

Comment: @BobJacobsen The explanation that you offered is applicable for the precessing mechanism of Earth satelites in Sun-synchronous orbit (SSO). The oblateness of the Earth gives rise to a force that averaged out tends to align satelite orbit with the Equator. Instead the orbital inclination remains fairly constant, and the orbit precesses. If you would string many satelites around in that orbit then that string of satellites is never in a common plane. In the case of a wheel: the wheel is rigid: any force is instantly transmitted to all parts of the wheel. Hence SSO explanation not applicable.

Comment: @BobJacobsen In the case of gyroscopic precession the rigidity of the gyro wheel is fundamental. Imagine a flexible disk, spin it at a velocity that the material isn't yet stretched to its max, and then try to change the orientation of the rotation axis. The material will flex all over the place. This illustrates that in the case of gyroscopic precession the rigidity of the gyro wheel is fundamental.

Comment: @BobJacobsen For many years now I have been recommending the following resources: (1) Feynman's discussion of gyroscopic precession in the FLP. [Book I, chapter 20](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_20.html), Feynman addresses a widespread misconception, starting with the words: 'some people like to say [...]' And he summerizes: 'It has to go down a little, in order to go around'. (2) Svilen Kostov and Daniel Hammer have conducted a [tabletop experiment](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1007/1007.5288.pdf) to verify Feynman's assertion experimentally.

Comment: I agree we're talking about rigid disks like gyroscopes, and that we're not talking about orbits, we're not talking about flexing disks. That's why the explanation works.  You disagree, and that's OK, but I note that you still haven't come up with a counterexample to 90 degree phase shift.  I'm content to let the votes of others see whether this is a useful way of thinking about it.

Comment: @BobJacobsen, ahh yes! Does this have to do with _virtual displacements_? That concept was always hard for me to grasp.

Comment: @BobJacobsen About a counterexample: usual gyro demo vid is a [bicycle wheel, hung by one side of the axle](https://www.exploratorium.edu/sites/default/files/f0409.gif). Non-spinning wheel: flops down when released. Sufficiently fast spinning wheel: when released starts precessing. I assume you do agree that a slow spinning wheel (barely a crawl) will flop down just like a non-spinning wheel. The point is: with barely a crawl the wheel does have a *non-zero angular momentum*. You appear to assert: no matter how small the angular momentum: if non-zero then precession *instead* of flopping down.

Comment: No, I don’t assert that. I only assert what I said.

Comment: @BobJacobsen My understanding of what you said: you assert that when the angular momentum of the wheel is non-zero then the response to exerted torque will be at 90 degrees to the exerted torque, *instead* of straight yielding to the torque. In your answer you describe it as: "the turning rotor tilts to the left, not forward"

Answer (score -2):

[image: image credit: Feynman Lectures on Physics book I chapter 20]

Image source: Feynman Lectures on Physics book I, chapter 20

The reasoning that Feynman presents is very indirect.

First: the discussion that Feynman offers here is for the case of a fast spinning wheel. When a wheel is spinning fast the gyroscopic effects are significantly larger than the inertia of the non-spinning wheel. For the purpose of simplicity Feynman treats the inertia of the non-spinning wheel as negligable compared to the gyroscopic effects of the fast spinning motion.

So: if the wheel would not be spinning you would need a bit of torque around the x-axis to get the reorientation depicted in fig. 20-2, but as I said, Feynman treats that one as negligable.

Feynman points out the following: the spinning wheel is subjected to rotation around the x-axis. The result of that is a *change* of the direction of the angular momentum of the spinning wheel. In the picture the length of the vector for the angular momentum is not to scale. Think of the angular momentum vector as a *very* *very* long vector. The vector $\Delta L$ represent the change from previous angular momentum to new angular momentum. Think of that vector $\Delta L$ as a *very* *very* long vector. (This is why Feynman only considers the corresponding torque, everything else by comparison negligable.)

Feynman then reasons as follows: the torque that corresponds to the vector $\Delta L$ is a torque around the z-axis. So: as you were reorienting the wheel from initial angular momentum to new angular momentum you must have been exerting the forces $F$ and $-F$ which both lie in the xy-plane.

Notice that here Feynman doesn't attempt to explain. He is laying out: if you apply the formulas as presented earlier in the chapter this is the result you get.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. If both $L$ and $\Delta L$ are _very very_ long vectors, how do they compare to one another? I would have thought $L$ >> $\Delta L$. Also, can you explain how Fig. 20-4 compares to Fig. 19.-4? I think I'm missing Feynman's point -Thanks!

Comment: @eball Here is my recommendation: buy a quality gyroscope and start feeling what it does. Compare different rotation rates, from slow to as fast you are able to spin it up. There is no substitute for feeling with your own hands what it does.

Comment: @eball I exaggerated. Indeed, since this example is for $\Delta \Theta$ a small value you get that $\Delta L$ << $L$  I should have concentrated on emphasizing that with a very large rotation rate the torque associated with gyroscopic effect is so much larger than the torque associated with the plain, non-gyroscopic inertia of the gyro wheel, that the plain inertia is by comparison negligable.

Comment: @eball I find the narratives to both fig 19-4 and fig 20-4 quite convoluted; unnecessarily complicated. I don't think they're helpful.

Comment: thanks. If that's true I guess it's not worth pursuing and understanding of Feynman's point for the time being (because it's convoluted and unnecessarily complicated).

Comment: @eball To avoid misunderstanding: in the FLP, overall the discussion of coriolis effect in ch. 19 and gyroscopic effect in ch. 20 is way superior to what I see in modern texbooks. It appears knowledge has been lost, presumably due to neglect. In the discussion of gyroscopic effect, I recommend study of the paragraphs surrounding the statement: 'it has to go down, in order to go around'. Feynman addresses a widespread misconception. Today that misconception is still as widespread, if not more. See also this [tabletop experiment](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1007/1007.5288.pdf)

Comment: Just to be clear, you are saying the two explanations (Coriolis Effect and Gyroscopic Effect) are superior on their own, but the connection he tries to make between them is not (because it's convoluted)?

Comment: @eball The stackexchange comment sections are by design not intended for conversation, and I endorse that design. For questions that require follow-up a threaded forum is a more suitable format. My preferred explanation of gyroscopic precession is in an answer I wrote in 2012, to a question titled, [What determines the direction of precession of a gyroscope](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/47645/17198). (I link only now because I want to avoid giving the impression of vanity linking.) (And yeah, that looong series of comments to Bob Jacobson is very much against my standard policy.)